# Rails 3 controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm writing an app with Rails 3. In my functional test, test/functional/cust_infos_controller_test.rb, I have these:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CustInfosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  # Replace this with your real tests.
  test "should get cust" do
    get :customerinfo
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns("cust_infos")
  end
end
```

My controller is fairly straightforward as it just finds all the customer's info:

```
class CustInfosController < ApplicationController
  def customerinfo
    @cust_info = CustInfo.find(:all, :order=>"cust_id")
    @cust_info.each do |ci|                                             
      if ci.upload_freq == 'W'
        ci.upload_freq = 'Weekly'
      elsif ci.upload_freq == 'M'
        ci.upload_freq = 'Monthly'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I ran it with:

```
$ ruby -Itest test/functional/cust_infos_controller_test.rb
```

I got the following error:

```
Loaded suite test/functional/cust_infos_controller_test
Started
E
Finished in 0.025258 seconds.

1) Error:
test_should_get_cust(CustInfosControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 4, scale 0 must round to an absolute value less than 10^4.

: INSERT INTO "cust_infos" ("cust_id") VALUES (298486374)


1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

In my cust_infos table, I have cust_id as integer. But I don't know why when I ran controller test to just get some record, active record will execute insert statement. How do I fix this?

UPDATE: I commented out all the lines in customerinfo method, and run the same test. Got the exact same result. So I'm guessing it's not my methods behavior, but rather Rails? Any hint?

Comment: can you post your customerinfo method?

Comment: I just posted it. It uses activerecord to find all the customers. That's all it does. And view will display the results.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do. What you need to do is create a helper for your view.

application_helper.rb

```
def display_upload_freq(s)
  case s
  when 'W'
    'Weekly'
  when 'M'
    'Monthly'
  end
end
```

cust_info_controller.rb

```
class CustInfosController < ApplicationController
  def customerinfo
    @cust_info = CustInfo.find(:all, :order=>"cust_id")
  end
end
```

Then in your view when your are iterating through @cust_info, for upload_freq, use dislay_upload_freq(ci.upload_freq). Assuming you have @cust_info.each do |ci|. Then you won't be confusing the db with saving anything.

Comment: I was trying to display this one attribute differently from what's in db. I didn't save it because the db doesn't need to be changed. I guess I could have built another model to do this. But thought it was just one attribute.

Comment: Changed answer to suite your needs. =)

Comment: Ok. That's a good way of doing it. Although it still didn't solve the test problem I had.

Comment: changing your controller to the above didn't change the test output?

Comment: also noticed you are testing for assert_not_nil assigns("cust_infos") and your instance variable name is @cust_info. So your assigns should be assigns('cust_info')

Comment: Yeah, I changed what you suggested here, including controller and test (assigns('cust_info')). But when I ran ruby -Itest test/functional/cust_infos_controller_test.rb again, the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using factories or fixtures to create your test data? If not, how are you creating it? My guess is that the insert is happening when your test data is being set up, not because of anything happening in your controller. The second part of that guess is borne out by the fact that commenting out all code in your controller isn't getting rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old, but I will post my answer in case someone is brought here by search engines.
I had the exact same problem, the issue originates from the fixture file(s) in test/fixtures/{name_of_your_model}.yml. Rails adds some initial values in this file, in my case it looked like this:

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
#  column: value
```

and when you want to run the test, it will try to create the test database using this fixtures. And that's where the issue occurs. Trying to create an empty record while you did not allow a null ID in your table.

Deleting these fixtures, or filling them with appropriate values should solve the problem.